# Visual Studio 2017 Test Explorer Trait Discovery: Shows more than TestCategory()

Tags: c#, traits, visual-studio-2017, test-explorer

In VS2017 all attributes seems to show up in the "Traits" view of Test Explorer. See below of the code and the Test Explorer Window. There used to only be so many attributes that would show up in the first place. **Does anyone know if there is a way to keep VS from discovering attributes that shouldn't be there?** There is no way that Description() and WorkItem() showing up in the test window helps. Each test would have a different description and then your test explorer would be bloated. Maybe this is a bug.......

Code:

```
    [TestCategory("Design - Login - Negative")]
    [TestCategory("Design")]
    [TestCategory("Negative")]
    [Description("Bob")]
    [WorkItem(7280), TestMethod]
    public async Task GetToken_Failure()
    {...}
```

Test Explorer Results:

[image]

Comment: So far, the only thing that I have been able to come up with is to create my own Attributes for WorkItem() and Description(). :( not happy!

    `public class Description : Attribute
    {
        public Description()
        {

        }

        private string description { get; set; }

        public Description(string TestDescription)
        {
            this.description = TestDescription;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS probably agreed that it was a bug as it no longer happens on VS 2017 community version 15.3.5

Comment: VS 2017, 15.7.5 has fixed a lot of this, Preview 15.8.0 preview 5.0 has fixed more of this problem.